# Como colocar uma imagem em uma string

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Gostaria de saber se seria possível  carregar uma imagem  dentro de uma string  em android através de um url de imagem? .

Comment: Não é duplicata a questao é diferente se analisar bem

Comment: É parecida e tu poderia facilmente ter editada sua pergunta anterior pra contemplar ela e ficar mais claro seu objetivo.

Comment: Pesquise como converter sua imagem para URI.